# how will I create this getnext function from this my suedocode

Tags: python-3.x, function

help me how will I create the getnext function

```
def getnext(atable, currind):
    """
    Given a list of lists, 'atable', and a list of indices one for each row in atable, 'currind',
    getnext changes currind in place to make it point to the "next" element in atable.
    It returns True if the change was successful, otherwise False.
    It also returns False if at least one index points outside atable,
    but the last element in currind, that is allowed to be -1 to make it possible
    to return pointers to the first element in atable.
    
    Example: atable = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j']]
             currind = [2, 0, 1, 0], points to ['c', 'd', 'f', 'i'].
             getnext(atable, currind) returns True and currind becomes:
             currind == [2, 0, 1, 1] pointing to ['c', 'd', 'f', 'j'].
             If you call again getnext(atable, currind) it returns True and currind becomes:
             currind == [2, 0, 2, 0] pointing to ['c', 'd', 'g', 'i'].
             If currind were [2, 0, 3, 2], getnext(atable, currind) would return False.
             To print the whole atable in order:
             currind = [0 for _ in atable]
             currind[-1] = -1
             while getnext(atable, currind):
             print([atable[r][c] for r, c in enumerate(currind)])
    """
```

Comment: This is what I have tried please help me finish it

Comment: Explore on `__iter__` functions

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: this is what I tried.  
def getnext(atable, currind):            
            if any((currind[pos] >=             len(atable[pos]):                                           for pos in range(len(currind))))):
            print("OutOfTable!")
            return False
  if any((pos < 0 for pos in currind[:-1]))
    print("Index < 0!")
  return False
  if currind[-1] < -1:
     print("LastIndex < -1!")